# parameter max size limit for post call in APEX callout

Tags: apex, callout

I want to post some data to EHR in call out. The data I am having is nearly 5000 characters of length and it cant be split up. It has to be sent in single attribute named "Description". I am not able to find the max character limit which can be send in a single attribute in APEX.

My request JSON for the post method is like this

```
en_billing_facility:1
en_facility:1
en_provider:12
en_date_service:2020-10-25
en_date_onset:2020-10-25
visit_type_cat:C
pid:1
en_pricelevel:Standard
en_attending:
en_nurse:
en_catid:25
input_time_zone:America/New_York
en_bill_notes:Test api
en_description :<5000 characters have to goes here>
```

In the above request , in en_description I need to pass nearly 5000 character of data

Comment: The http body has a limit on the implementation side, 6MB for synchronous and 12MB for asynchronous Apex. It is not clear what you mean by a "a single attribute in APEX". Including your payload format and any issues you are encountering in a post [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/346198/edit) will help. Consider heap allocation if your "single attribute" is built and held in memory of your transaction too.

Comment: @TSmith have edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are limited to at minimum 6MB of callout body data per transaction, as listed in [Execution Governors and Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm). As such, you should only hit about 6KB of data per callout in your scenario, and this is perfectly acceptable. Note that the maximum length of a string is also at least 6MB, of which your entire payload must fit in anyways, since that's the maximum length of a string. Note that for asynchronous code and incoming email handlers, those limits are instead 12MB and 36Mb, respectively. There's also a 100-callout-per-transaction limit, so even though you won't use 6MB of data, you'll still have to design your code to limit itself to 100 callouts per transaction, if applicable.